# p2os gazebo simulation example stopped working on electric

Tags: ros, gazebo, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to setup Pioneer 3dx simulation in gazeebo in electric. Following is the shell output:

```
nitin@nitin-desktop:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/p2os/p2os_urdf/launch$ roslaunch pioneer3dx.gazebo.launch 
... logging to /home/nitin/.ros/log/960257d8-6ea9-11e1-9c88-3cd92b6407b7/roslaunch-nitin-desktop-10724.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://localhost:40448/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /pr2_controller_manager/joint_state_publish_rate
 * /use_sim_time
 * /rosdistro
 * /robot_description
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency
 * /pr2_controller_manager/mechanism_statistics_publish_rate
 * /rosversion
 * /robot_state_publisher/tf_prefix

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)
    spawn_pioneer (gazebo/spawn_model)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    pr2_mechanism_diagnostics (pr2_mechanism_diagnostics/pr2_mechanism_diagnostics)
    diffdrive (gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_diffdrive)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [10745]
process[spawn_pioneer-2]: started with pid [10746]
process[robot_state_publisher-3]: started with pid [10747]
process[pr2_mechanism_diagnostics-4]: started with pid [10748]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 0.10.0

Part of the Player/Stage Project [http://playerstage.sourceforge.net].
Copyright (C) 2003 Nate Koenig, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the GNU General Public License.

process[diffdrive-5]: started with pid [10749]
loading model xml from ros parameter
attempting to spawn robot in simulation
waiting for service spawn_urdf_model
directory [/tmp/gazebo-nitin-0] already exists (previous crash?)
the owner gazebo server (pid=9299) is not running.
deleting the old information of the directory [/tmp/gazebo-nitin-0]
Param [quickStep] is deprecated: [replace quickStep with stepType]
Param [quickStepIters] is deprecated: [replace quickStepIters with stepIters]
Param [quickStepW] is deprecated: [replace quickStepW with stepW]
Gazebo successfully initialized
/tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:99 : Exception: Failed to load libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Main simulation loop failed
/tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:99 : Exception: Failed to load libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
spawning success None
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 10745, exit code -11].
```

am i missing some package? Installation is done through precompiled debs.

prince

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29759/p2os-gazebo-simulation-example-stopped-working-on-electric/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-15**:
solved the problem as in thread http://answers.ros.org/question/12032/service-call-failed-while-launching-the-gazebo by Martin. The package required is found in pr2_simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

solved the problem as in thread http://answers.ros.org/question/12032/service-call-failed-while-launching-the-gazebo by Martin. The package required is found in pr2_simulator

How can I close this question now??

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-09**:
Admin's can come by and close your own question for you.